# Checking The Status Code of a Future Method From Another Class

Tags: flutter

I' trying to check status code of a future method from another class. I'm also wondering, let's say I have a mapped data in this future, can I use that in another class?

Comment: Show your code where the error occurred or where you have problems.

Comment: actually, there is no specific code. I'm just wondering, can I do this? If yes, what is the way to do this?

Comment: The sentence you use is vague. What do you mean use something in another class? You can pass arguments to the constructor of any class. Just define the class and add the arguments. And yes, you can call a method of a class, async (not future) or otherwise from a method of another class. Pretty standard programming paradigms. Asynchronous methods return a Future.

Comment: Maybe give examples of the classes you are thinking of. Paste their codes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some examples of what I think you were asking:

```
class ClassOne {
  ...
  Future<int> getStatus() {
    var status = 0;
    // do some lengthy stuff here
    status = ...
    return status;
  }
  
  Future<Map<String, String>> getMappedData() {
    final myMap = Map<String, String>();
    ...
    // populate the map
    ...
    return myMap;
  }
}

class ClassTwo {
  ...
  final classOne = ClassOne();
  ...
  void someMethod() async {
    int status;
    ...
    status = await classOne.getStatus();
    // use the status code here
  }
  ...
  void anotherMethod() async {
    Map<String, String> map;
    ...
    map = await classOne.getMappedData();
    // use your map here
  }
}
```